# Importing PDF causing an error of URIError: Pathname cannot be decoded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I am trying to create a download button for a user to download a pdf from the browser. I have the pdf file in a folder inside my repo Ive added:

```
{
   test: /\.pdf$/,
   use: "raw-loader",
},
```

to my webpack which solved the issue of it not compiling. But now i am getting an error that says

```
URIError: Pathname "%PDF-1.7
... " could not be decoded. This is likely caused by an invalid percent-encoding.
```

my component is pretty simple

```
import React from "react";
import CGXPDF from "../../images/SDPA_CGX.pdf";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const PDFDownloadButton = ({ visitType }) => {

  return (
    <Link to={CGXPDF} target="_blank">Download Requisition Form</Link>
  );
};
```

I am still new to developing so any help would me very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be the `use: "raw-loader"` in my webpack. Changing it to `use: ["file-loader"],` resolved this issue.